# grails named queries giving null when using get() in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock, named-query

I have a `domain` with [named query](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html):

```
class Publication {
   String title
   String author

   static namedQueries = {
       publicationsWithBookInTitle {
           like 'title', '%Book%'
       }
   }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return title
    }
}
```

and in `controller` I have

```
def show() {
    Publication publicationInstance = Publication.publicationsWithBookInTitle.get()

    println "Get: ${publicationInstance}"
    println "List: ${Publication.publicationsWithBookInTitle.list()}"

    respond publicationInstance
}
```

and my `unit test`:

```
void "test show"() {
    given:
    Publication publication = new Publication(title: 'MyBook', author: 'MB').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    when:
    controller.show()

    then:
    model.publicationInstance == publication
}
```

When I run the test it gives me null when using get() method and my test fails. System output is

```
Get: null
List: [MyBook ]
```

I search for this but not found any solution of this issue.

**Why this is happening and what is the solution or workaround of this issue?**

**NOTE:-** I am currently using `grails 2.3.9`. But my project initially created in `grails 2.3.5` then upgraded to `grails 2.3.9`.

Comment: a dumb thing, but sometimes when strange errors happens i try to clean the project. Have you tried this?

Comment: @meurer Yes I have tried this but no luck.

Comment: Worked for me in 2.3.9 and 2.4.2.

Comment: @dmahapatro - OK, Then may be project specific issue. I will create a sample project and test it. Will update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: @dmahapatro - Yes you are right, it is working in `grails 2.3.9`. My project initially created in `grails 2.3.5` then upgraded to `grails 2.3.9`. I have created a sample app in `grails 2.3.5` and it is failing in it. I have also upgraded it and the result is same, failing.

Comment: I tend to create a whole new app with the newest version and then port code from old to the new project to avoid these kind of hassles. Good that you found it out.

Comment: @dmahapatro - I have found the solution. The hibernate plugin version in the application is `hibernate:3.6.10.6` when I upgrade it to `hibernate:3.6.10.15` fix the issue (https://grails.org/2.3.9+Release+Notes). Your comment shows me the correct way. Want to mark that as answer. Can you post your comment with this information. Thanks..,.

Comment: I just validated the issue. I would rather suggest "you" to add your finding as an answer and **accept it** for others who would face this issue in future. Glad that you spent time to find the root cause. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally with the help of *dmahapatro* comment I figure out the root cause (@dmahapatro **THANKS**).

Named queries gives correct result in `grails 2.3.9`. But my project is upgraded from `grails 2.3.5` which is using `hibernate:3.6.10.6` and haven't changed to the `hibernate:3.6.10.15` as recommended in the [grails 2.3.9 release notes](https://grails.org/2.3.9+Release+Notes). Once I upgraded the project hibernate version my issue resolved.

**NOTE:-** You will face the issue if you are using `grails 2.3.5`.